# Browse the internet using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to access the internet using Python. And I have written a small program. But, I'm getting many errors that don't make sense to me.

Here is the program:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

And here are the errors:

```
"C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Python Tutorials\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Python Tutorials/Facebook.py"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Python Tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Python Tutorials/Facebook.py", line 10, in <module>
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
      File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Python Tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
        self.service.start()
      File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Python Tutorials\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
        raise WebDriverException(
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Now, I used your suggestion and it worked for me. I guess I can now not only open the google.com website but can also open the Facebook website along with my ID and Password.

The main problem when I was not able to install webdrivermanager because, I found there are two packages, webdrivermanager and webdriver-manager. I have been trying to install webdrivermanager and it kept giving me an error while trying to install it, but when I install webdriver-manager it allowed me to install successfully and it's working for me now.

Please check this by yourself, here :

I'm trying to open up google.com website then it closes automatically and then its asking me for my login ID and then password and then it opens another firefox webpage where it shows me a homepage for Facebook.

over here, I also put # next to the previous command and tried to run, which ran successfully. I would like to give credit to 'geeksforgeeks.com' website from where I picked up most of the code.

Comment: `Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.` this clearly mentioned that the `geckodriver` path is missing.

Comment: First Part:from selenium import webdriver
##from webdriver.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://google.com")

driver.quit()
from time import sleep

usr = input('Enter Email Id:')
pwd = input('Enter Password:')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
print("Opened facebook")
sleep(1)

Comment: Second Part:username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
username_box.send_keys(usr)
print("Email Id entered")
sleep(1)

password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('pass')
password_box.send_keys(pwd)
print("Password entered")

login_box = driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton')
login_box.click()

print("Done")
input('Press anything to quit')
driver.quit()
print("Finished")

Comment: I was able to open the facebook website successfully using this code. For some reason, it didn't allowed me paste this on my original question.

Answer (score 0):

`Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. this clearly mentioned that the geckodriver path is missing.` and there are many answers that you can find when you search with that message on Stackoverflow.

However, I would prefer using Weddriver-manger library which will download the driver and take necessary steps to initiate browser with minimal effort.

Try the below snippet.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

driver.quit()
```

Make sure `Webdriver-manager` library is added to the project. Below is the screenshot for pycharm
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I tried this approach and now i'm down to only one error. File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Python Tutorials/Facebook.py", line 7, in <module> from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager' Process finished with exit code 1 However, I tried to install webdriver manager using the command pip install webdrivermanager from cmd, it went successfully, but again when I tried to install the package from Pycharm it failed and thew me error.

Comment: check with the updated answer where I added the screenshot to show how to add the library to your project.

Comment: I tried to look for this as you suggested, but it doesn't show me webdriver-manager there.